# how to unmap and free the highmem pages in linux module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I allocated  and mapped highmem pages in my init method of a module:

```
highmem_page = alloc_pages( GFP_HIGHUSER, 3 );
if ( ! highmem_page ) printk(KERN_ERR "Couldn't allocate highmem page with order : 3\n" );
  else {
    highmem_page_address = kmap( highmem_page );
    if ( ! highmem_page_address ) printk( KERN_ERR "Couldn't map highmem pages.\n");
    else {
      printk( KERN_ERR "Address for highuser pages is : %lx. Order: %d.\n", 
            highmem_page_address,
            3
           );
     }
  }
```

Which worked well and generated output in log. via `dmesg`:

> [ 4065.975025] Address for highuser pages is : ffff88002c5d0000.
>   Order: 3.

Now, in exit, I'm doing something like this:

```
kunmap(highmem_page); //will unmap only ? can it free too? highly doubtful!
__free_pages( highmem_page, 3 ); //will free the pages?
```

I think `kunmap()` should unmap the highmem pages from the kernel's virtual address space. **Is my understanding right here**? Then `__free_pages()` should free the allocated pages.

However when I rmmod it,  `dmesg` shows something I don't anticipate:

```
[ 4109.529834] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffeb880002c5dc
[ 4109.529845] IP: [<ffffffff8111e999>] __free_pages+0x9/0x40
[ 4109.529856] PGD 0 
[ 4109.529861] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[ 4109.529866] CPU 0 
[ 4109.529869] Modules linked in: prob4(O-) 
...
[ 4109.529943] 
[ 4109.529948] Pid: 5060, comm: rmmod Tainted: G           O 3.2.6 #4 TOSHIBA T20             /T20             
[ 4109.529956] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8111e999>]  [<ffffffff8111e999>] __free_pages+0x9/0x40
[ 4109.529963] RSP: 0018:ffff88002c5b5e78  EFLAGS: 00010216
[ 4109.529967] RAX: 000001880002c5c0 RBX: ffffea0000b17400 RCX: 0000000000000024
[ 4109.529970] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000006 RDI: ffffeb880002c5c0
[ 4109.529974] RBP: ffff88002c5b5e78 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000005
[ 4109.529978] R10: ffffea0000b18018 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffffffa024f2f8
[ 4109.529981] R13: ffff88002c5b5f18 R14: 00007fffe3342480 R15: 0000000000000001
[ 4109.529986] FS:  00007f927f6d4700(0000) GS:ffff88005f400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 4109.529990] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[ 4109.529993] CR2: ffffeb880002c5dc CR3: 000000002c537000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
[ 4109.529997] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[ 4109.530000] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[ 4109.530005] Process rmmod (pid: 5060, threadinfo ffff88002c5b4000, task ffff88005b0416e0)
[ 4109.530008] Stack:
[ 4109.530010]  ffff88002c5b5ea8 ffffffff8111ea14 ffff88002c5b5e98 ffffffff00000006
[ 4109.530017]  ffff88002c5b5ec8 0000000000000007 ffff88002c5b5ec8 ffffffffa024d049
[ 4109.530024]  0000000000000880 ffffffffa024f000 ffff88002c5b5f78 ffffffff810a4cde
[ 4109.530031] Call Trace:
[ 4109.530037]  [<ffffffff8111ea14>] free_pages+0x44/0x50
[ 4109.530043]  [<ffffffffa024d049>] my_pager_exit+0x49/0x1000 [prob4]
[ 4109.530051]  [<ffffffff810a4cde>] sys_delete_module+0x19e/0x270
[ 4109.530059]  [<ffffffff81645102>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 4109.530062] Code: 04 25 d8 05 01 00 8b 4d b8 48 8b 55 c0 e9 fe fe ff ff 31 d2 48 89 de e8 06 c6 ff ff e9 6d ff ff ff 90 55 48 89 e5 66 66 66 66 90 <8b> 47 1c f0 ff 4f 1c 0f 94 c0 84 c0 74 09 85 f6 74 0d e8 60 d8 
[ 4109.530120] RIP  [<ffffffff8111e999>] __free_pages+0x9/0x40
[ 4109.530125]  RSP <ffff88002c5b5e78>
[ 4109.530127] CR2: ffffeb880002c5dc
[ 4109.530132] ---[ end trace 2dcb27dca5b2d882 ]---
```

`ffffeb880002c5dc` is no where in my code. Why is it going there?

And now, what do I do?

```
R# rmmod prob4
ERROR: Removing 'prob4': Device or resource busy
```

Since unloading is not happening.

So, how do I unmap and free the allocated pages from HIGHMEM?

EDIT:

BTW, same question has not yielded any results at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98498/how-to-unmap-and-free-the-highmem-pages that's why I am asking it here. And also, this question contains actual bug related to programming. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate multiple contiguous physical pages, then map only the first one.
If your kernel module accesses memory from the other two, weird things may happen.

The way this is usually done throughout the kernel is that if you need more than one page, you have a loop in which you:

```
1. call alloc_page to get a physical page.
2. map it with kmap.
```

When releasing, you need to loop over all pages and:

```
1. call kunmap.
2. call free_page.
```

You might also consider the good old kmalloc, it saves some trouble if you only want a small amount of memory.